# V8 shell and reading from stdin

Tags: javascript, v8

I use v8-shell for my research. I need from my JS-scripts to be able to read 'stdin'.

For example, I run a JS-script as: cat textfile.txt | ./v8-shell myscript.js

In my 'myscript.js' I need to read the data passed to stdin.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v8 provides no I/O libraries. It is basically only a runtime for the core JavaScript language, with some objects like Math, String and Array provided as a part.

The lack of *vital* modules like I/O is because they have no use in a browser environment and v8 is implemented as a component of a such environment. To be able to use v8 as a standalone programming environment, one needs to have native libraries for at least basic I/O. Here you have two choices: To implement an I/O extension to v8 or use an existing one. The former will requrie C++ knowledge, as v8 is implemented in C++ and provides apis for extensions in C++. The latter option is more easy. You can choose between many implementations of such libraries.

One popular library is [node.js](http://nodejs.org), which provides a exhaustive event-driven, mostly asynchronous api for I/O and networking. If you can use [node.js](http://nodejs.org), access to stdin, stdout and stderr is provided in it via the [process](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html) module. *Quicklink: [process.stdin](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_stdin).*

One other project is [CommonJs](http://commonjs.org), which is a list specs and a whole lot of implementations of it, dedicated to provide API's (with or without I/O) for use of JS outside of a browser enviroment. Many implementations are on top of v8, which are listed in http://commonjs.org/impl/.

Another such project is Gnome's [Seed](https://live.gnome.org/Seed), which provides an API, including GObjectInstrospection. It also uses a custom JS runtime, so if you need to stick to v8, this is not an option for you. What also noteworthy about Seed is it's implemented and extensible in C language.

Comment: I know how to do this with Node.js, but I'm interested in a solution with v8-shell only.

Comment: @niXman I don't think the v8 implementation provides a standard javascript library. But I'm building v8 right now, I'll extend my answer with results.

Comment: @niXman I have extended my answer to provide a real, detailed answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @G.Kayaalp: CommonJS maintains a list of specification, and not all engines that implement some of them provide IO. The relevant link would be http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/System

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for noticing. I've realised that although I haven't used the word I/O in the relevant paragraph, it implicitly may mean it. I'll fix it ASAP.

Comment: I wrote a patch for v8-shell that implements the getchar() and getline() functions: http://pastebin.com/Dyqvuv5x

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. You can use the `readline()` function.

I don't see it in the ECMAScript specification but Google [v8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/3.29.84/src/d8.cc), WebKit's JavaScriptCore and Mozilla [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell) all support it (and have been supporting for quite some time).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [teajs](http://code.google.com/p/teajs/wiki/API) which conforms to common.js and is based on v8 - it is the only project that I know off which let's you build an apache 'mod_teajs' module (node.js server is not production ready in my opinion) and it does have standard IO.

```
stdin
system.stdin.read(count) - read count bytes from standard input. The data is returned as an instance of Buffer. If count == 0, all available data is read. 
system.stdin.readLine([count]) - reads a line from standard input. If count is not specified, reads up to 65535 bytes. When no data is available, returns null. 

stdout
system.stdout.write(data) - write data to standard output. Data can be either string or Buffer. 
system.stdout.writeLine(data) - write data followed by a line break to standard output. Data can be either string or Buffer. 
system.stdout.flush() - flushes stdout 

stderr
system.stderr.write(data) - write data to standard error output. Data can be either string or Buffer. 
system.stderr.writeLine(data) - write data followed by a line break to standard error output. Data can be either string or Buffer. 
system.stderr.flush() - flushes stderr
```